# Android ZXING barcodescan put result value in string

Tags: java, android, zxing, zxing.net

I am trying to get the result value in a string after there has been scanned.
 but it wont work.

I already figured out how to put it in a  toast(maketext) that works but a string I cant figure it out.
 here's the code please help me.

```
        cpackage com.example.stage.absa;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import java.io.IOException;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import android.net.Uri;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AbsRuntimePermission {

    String resultCode;
    private Button getBtn;
    private TextView result;
    private OkHttpClient client;
    boolean doubleTap = false;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 10;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        getBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWebService();
            }
        });
        client = new OkHttpClient();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                R.string.msg, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleTap) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Druk Terug opnieuw om de app te sluiten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            doubleTap = true;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleTap = false;
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void browser1(View view) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.suppliance.nl/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public void scanCode(View view) {
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZxingScannerResultHandler());

        setContentView(scannerView);
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }

    class ZxingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
           // String resultCode = result.getText();
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resultCode = result.getText();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            scannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    }



    private void getWebService() {

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("http")
                .appendPath(getString(R.string.ipadres))
                .appendPath(getString(R.string.poort))
                .authority("barcode/")
                .appendPath(getString(R.id.))
        String URL = builder.build().toString();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.17.12:9083/barcode/8712345501006").build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.setText("Mislukt");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            result.setText(response.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            result.setText("Error tijdens verkrijgen body");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode) {
        //Do anything when permisson granted
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toegang geaccepteerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the code that works or not?? because you posted something using Strings and Toast....?

Comment: Yes this code works but i dont get it because i have decleared an variable havent i ? and i just cant use it further in the mainactivity file thats what i want to be able to do

Comment: You need to declare the property `String resultCode` at class level, and not inside the handleResult method if you want to use it in other parts (You should put this anonymous class inside your MainActivity for simplicity)

Comment: @MatPag what exact line of code do i need to move and to where ?

Comment: In the same place where you are using the `ZxingScannerResultHandler` class, try to follow [this](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner#simple-usage) code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the String declaration and instead move it as a class member

```
 public void handleResult(Result result) {
            //String resultCode = result.getText();
             resultCode = result.getText();
```

like:

```
myClass extends Activity... {
      String resultCode;
}
```

now you can assign the result code in the hadnleResult  callback and use it in the same activity whenever you need it!

---

Edit:

you have an inner class, i would get rid of that and directly implement the `ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler` interface:

example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AbsRuntimePermission  implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{

    private String resultCode;
    private Button getBtn;
    private TextView result;
    private OkHttpClient client;
    boolean doubleTap = false;
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 10;
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        getBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getBtn);
        getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getWebService();
            }
        });
        client = new OkHttpClient();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        requestAppPermissions(new String[]{
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                R.string.msg, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleTap) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Druk Terug opnieuw om de app te sluiten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            doubleTap = true;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleTap = false;
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void browser1(View view) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.suppliance.nl/"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    public void scanCode(View view) {
        scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        //scannerView.setResultHandler(new ZxingScannerResultHandler());
        scannerView.setResultHandler(this);

        setContentView(scannerView);
        scannerView.startCamera();
    }

    //class ZxingScannerResultHandler implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result) {
           // String resultCode = result.getText();
           // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            resultCode = result.getText();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            scannerView.stopCamera();
        }
    //}



    private void getWebService() {

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("http")
                .appendPath(getString(R.string.ipadres))
                .appendPath(getString(R.string.poort))
                .authority("barcode/")
                .appendPath(getString(R.id.))
        String URL = builder.build().toString();

        final Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.17.12:9083/barcode/8712345501006").build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        result.setText("Mislukt");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            result.setText(response.body().string());
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            result.setText("Error tijdens verkrijgen body");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode) {
        //Do anything when permisson granted
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toegang geaccepteerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this look the code above pls but it still doesnt work why ?

Comment: then post the hole class... we can not help you by guessing what you wrote!

Comment: my answer got edited! take a look, give a try and let me know!

Comment: i just copied/pasted the code and it doesnt work atleast i am still not able to use the variable in the activity do i need to change anything in your edit like in (handleResult or something else )? could you maybe like finish it so i just would be done or is that not possible ?

Comment: i litterly cant figure it out so would be amazed if you could help me i just want to have the scanned value in the  .appendPath(getString(R.id.)); doesnt have to be a string just want the value there

Comment: let me know what is not working? do you get an error in the IDE??

Comment: i am not getting any errors but am still not able with the exact code that you just re-edited to use the string variable resultCode in (getWebService) .appendPath(getString(R.id.));

Comment: Laten we een chat openen!

Comment: do you want to put the scanned qrcode in the ***Request request***??

Comment: yeah but first i will need the value in the Uri.Builder builder to make the url what i want is to have the scanned qrcode value in the getWebService just like ipadres and poort see code so i can make an URL and use it later

Comment: did you tried ***.appendPath(resultCode)*** in the ***Uri.Builder builder***

Comment: Yeah that's it much thanks!!! only one more question why do i need to have .appendPath(getString(R.string.ipadres)) and cant use .appendPath(ipadres) like .appendPath(resultCode)?

Comment: Hummm, ***R.string.ipadres*** is defined in the xml resources maybe and instead, the resultCode is an string object... android uses different ways to get the data depending on where is declared!

Comment: Eyy i have another problem could you help me PLSSS on that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260619/android-zxing-scanned-value-used-in-custom-url-to-make-get-http-request-and-retr i wanted to chat with you but haven't got enought REP :( already much thanks

Comment: Could you please take  a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44260619/android-zxing-scanned-value-used-in-custom-url-to-make-get-http-request-and-retr

Answer (score 0):

I will go with this or something similar, depending on how you are handling the scanner view

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
                  implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    private String resultCode;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        resultCode = rawResult.getText();
        //now use resultCode
    }
}
```